# Document Uploading

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm, document

I am working on Document upload feature present in MS CRM 2011. However while uploading a document we have to provide share point URL.

Could you please help me out how to get share point URL?

I don't have no idea about share point

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM and Sharepoint are different products. You need to have installed Sharepoint in order to use it. The URL required to configure CRM will be the address of the document library where you wish CRM to start storing your documents.

In any case, I think that this question best belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com) so I have flagged it to be moved.

Answer (score 0):

When you install SharePoint and create your first web application you can choose what the majority of the URL looks like. it will also be the URL you use to navigate to the site.